# Angular 2 shows two components for one route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

For a little project I experience strange behaviour for `Angular CLI: 1.7.4` and `Node: 9.11.1`. The main Problem is that the app shows two different pages (Overview + Detail) upon double-click, but for contextmenu > click it works as expected (only showing Detail) although they use the same method for redirect.

The image shows the expected DOM (=works for contextmenu > click) and the actual result for double-click:
[image: expected result (above) and actual result (below)]

`app-routing.module.ts`: (my main routing file)

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'overview', component: OverviewComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { title: 'Produktionskette' } },
  { path: 'options', component: OptionComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { title: 'Optionen' } },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, data: { title: 'Anmelden' } },
  { path: 'details/:id', component: DetailComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService], data: { title: 'Details' } },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/overview', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/overview' }
];

@NgModule({
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The components are very basic and interact with vanilla-JS together with jQuery. In the **diagram** the context menu is initialized as:

```
context.find(".contextView").click(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    context.hide();
    if (selectedDevice) {
        showDeviceDetails(selectedDevice);
    }
});
```

The double-click is initialized inside every **device** (for each device):

```
object.dblclick(() => diagram.showDeviceDetails(_this));
```

The Angular 2 components are defined as follows:

`overview.component.ts`: (/overview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.css']
})

export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  // does not do very much, just loading etc
}
```

`detail.component.ts`: (details/:id)

```
Component({
  selector: 'app-detail',
  templateUrl: './detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./detail.component.css']
})
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {
  // also works as intended
}
```

Could this be a routing problem? As said both doubleclick and contextmenu>click use the same method and both execution types work inside the detail-component.

Comment: Did you check for console errors?

Comment: Of course, there are no errors in the console.